# Fixed Position element changes color when scrolling down to a new page

Tags: html, css, svg

I saw the [Google Material Design website](https://material.io/gallery/) and was amazed by the change of color of the left, sticky "speech bubble"-image when you scroll down.

I am trying to understand the concept but Google's code is huge and somewhat confusing...
I think there are actually two images, but I cant recreate it just with different z-index values alone (I can let the first image disappear and the first appear but in combination it doesn't work).

Do I need a JS-library for that? `Waypoints/scrollreveal` etc., is this some kind of SVG magic or am I overlooking a simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

on simple usage try onScroll() method using js for applying basic css colors on your element.

Answer (score 0):

- I believe those are animated objects, and the sections (their containers) have overflow:hidden, so those objects stay within their sections.
- Also they probably have position:fixed and positioned using'top' and 'left' properties to stay on place all the time (or probably some JavaScript magic).
- And ther animation is launched using JavaScript function scrollTop(), when visitor is on a certain distance from a page top.
- I'm not sure what is used in this exactly page, but you can change and adjust scale, size, color and transparency depending on position from page top using JavaScrip - 100%.

Comment: Yes. If you look at the HTML, each section has its own SVG which is `position: fixed`. They are all lined up directly over each other and different SVGs are revealed as you scroll the page.

Comment: I was only partially successful with your suggestions. For some reason, the images/elements I used only disappear downwards, but not upwards. They appear together and vanish one by one. It also took me a while to figure out the parent container had to be position: relative... Can you guys tell me what I have to do get these elements to truly behave like in the website? I prepared a simple jsfiddle to showcase the problem: 
https://jsfiddle.net/x4x1v878/